# Javascript window.onload function not loading for multiple charts with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I'm using Chart.js to display some charts.
When I use the onload function for the pie chart it loads correctly on the page, when I add a second variable to onload for bar-chart, nothing will display.

My javascript code looks like this

```
    var config = {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
        data : [10, 30, 40, 50],
        backgroundColor: [
                "#F7464A",
                "#46BFBD",
                "#FDB45C",
                "#949FB1",
                "#65b13b",

            ],
        }],
        labels: ["4G", "5G", "Mano"],
    },
        options: {
        responsive: true
    }
};

var barChartData = {
    type: 'bar',
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            },
            {
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
            }
        ]
    options: {
        responsive: true

    },

};

window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
};
    var bctx = document.getElementById("bar-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(bctx, barChartData);
};
```

My html code looks like this:

```
<canvas id="bar-chart" class="chart-holder" height="250" width="538"></canvas>
<canvas id="pie-chart" class="chart-holder" height="250" width="538"></canvas>
```

I've looked at other solutions but they are all very complicated and I feel like it's only something simple.

Comment: You need to get rid of that stray `};` between those two parts of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The `bar-chart` code is outside the `window.onload` function. Put that inside the `window.onload` function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);

    var bctx = document.getElementById("bar-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(bctx, barChartData);
};
```